# Making 3 PNG images buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a GUI for my final year project, so to make it more ergonomic I've suggested a simple design as shown in the picture, so as I'm still a beginner in HTML/CSS I tried multiple ways to find how to turn an image to a button, and that button will start another function which starts capturing video with a webcam, so for me, the most important is how to make the buttons as shown in the picture.
[image]

here is my HTML code:

```
<section class="lg">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </nav>
</section>
```

and here is the CSS linked with:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.lg{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/Background2.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;

}
nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: We aren't a homework solving website, please make the code yourself. Utilize anchor tags to make them clickable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a.

Answer (score 0):

just place the image inside a button or place the image in an <a>

```js
function test(){
location.href="https://stackoverflow.com"
console.log("button")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="test()"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25"></button>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25"></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain your code in an edit.

Comment: This will make whole image to be clickable, as I could've understand from question, every button (as shown per image) should lead to another page. 

@ethry made me laugh, ngl.

Comment: @str1ng I like saying that to old accounts with lots of rep lol

Comment: Aha! So my account is still fresh (yay!) @ethry

Answer (score 0):

This way, you're making whole image clickable, another approach is to have img and to create clickable areas, here's an example (of course you will have to update the coordinates inside of the `coords` attribute):

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="usemap" usemap="#lessons"/>
      <map name = "lessons">
         <area shape="poly" coords="74,0,113,29,98,72,52,72,38,27"
            href="placeyouwannago" alt="Start capture" target="_blank">
         <area shape="rect" coords="22,83,126,125" alt="Input"
            href="placeyouwannago" target="_blank">
         <area shape="circle" coords = "73,168,32" alt="Settings"
            href="placeyouwannago" target="_blank">
      </map>
```

Check documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map